# Each of 4 players recieved 13 cards out of 52

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Each of 4 players received 13 cards out of 52. Calculate the probability that all players received at least one spade. I am looking for the solution that would be like: $1-\mathbb{P}(A^\prime)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Inclusion-Exclusion principle, it is:
1-4*Pr(A is void in spades)+6*Pr(A,B are void)-4*Pr(A,B,C are void)

$A$ is void in spades with probability ${39\choose13}/{52\choose13}$.
$A,B$ are void in spades with probability ${39\choose 26}/{52\choose26}$.

Step 1: 1-Pr(A is void)-Pr(B is void)-Pr(C is void)-Pr(D is void).
Step 2: We double-removed the cases when A,B are both void, so replace them once.
Also, when A,C are both void.  Also when ....
Step 3: Now consider when three players are void, how many times has this been counted, and removed?
Step 4: Now consider when all four players are void in spades.

Comment: I have no idea where does this come from, could you write on that a bit more?

Comment: still i do not think i get it

Comment: Look up on the net about Inclusion-Exclusion

Comment: Thus the probability is $4\times \frac{39 \choose 13}{52 \choose 13}-{{4}\choose{2}}\times\frac{26 \choose 13}{ 52 \choose 13}+{{4}\choose{3}}\times\frac{1}{52 \choose 13}$?

Comment: Check the signs of the terms - you exclude voids from the total probability.

Comment: I've changed that that it will be obviously $1-P(A^\prime)$ thus the signs will "swap" (plus to minus etc.)

Comment: Am i correct or not?

Comment: Still i would appreciate an answer.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Appreciate your help